# Mysql search & replace with random characters

Tags: mysql, wordpress, search

I have in text some URLS `src="https://example.com/public/images/someimage.jpg?itok=WDGFySy"`
I need remove in every url this garbage token `?itok=WDGFySy`, all tokens obviously are random :).
I try do it directly in database like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'itok=[[:xdigit:]]{8}', '') WHERE post_content LIKE 'itok=[[:xdigit:]]{8}
';
```

But i cant find any of this tokens like this. `LIKE this [a-fA-F0-9]{8}` also wont help. Any advice? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use regex if you have MySQL 8.0.

However, if your links are in separate fields, it is possible to create and use SP to clean them up:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CLEANUP(
      aString VARCHAR(255)
    , aName VARCHAR(15)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    SET @u = SUBSTRING_INDEX(aString, '?', 1);
    SET @q = SUBSTRING_INDEX(aString, '?', -1);

    IF @q = aString THEN
        RETURN aString; -- no '?' char found
    ELSE
        SET @f = LOCATE(CONCAT(aName, '='), @q);
        SET @query = IF(@f > 1, SUBSTR(@q, 1, @f - 1), '');
        IF @f > 0 THEN
            SET @t = LOCATE('&', @q, @f + LENGTH(aName) + 1);
            IF @t > 0 THEN
                SET @query = CONCAT(@query, SUBSTR(@q, @t + 1));
            END IF;
        END IF;

        IF @query = '' THEN
            RETURN @u;
        ELSE
            RETURN CONCAT(@u, '?', TRIM('&' FROM @query));
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then:

```
SELECT
      CLEANUP('https://example.com/public/images/someimage.jpg?itok=WDGFySy&b=2', 'itok')
    , CLEANUP('https://example.com/public/images/someimage.jpg?itok=WDGFySy', 'itok')
    , CLEANUP('https://example.com/public/images/someimage.jpg?a=1&itok=WDGFySy', 'itok')
    , CLEANUP('https://example.com/public/images/someimage.jpg?a=1&itok=WDGFySy&b=2', 'itok')
;
```